# Pass arguments to mixin from single variable array

Tags: list, sass, arguments, mixins

I have the next mixin:

```
@mixin mymixin($arguments...){...}
```

commonly we can call the mixin in this way:

```
@include mymixin(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

but in this case i have the next variable

```
$arguments: (arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I want call the mixin and pass $arguments variable...
is there a way to do this? is like javascript `apply()`

Note that $arguments is dinamic size, and mixin takes all arguments and parse each one.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass a list to a mixin that takes an arglist by adding ellipsis when calling the mixin:

```
@include mymixin($arguments...);
```

Source: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1849